# How to get a single member from a group in Phaser 3?

Tags: javascript, html, phaser-framework

In my Phaser 3 game I have a group called OBS. Now my game requires to randomly get a member from OBS and detect collision between the group member (from OBS) and another sprite called Player. I looked up docs but couldn't figure it out.

[Group - Notes of Phaser 3](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/group/&ved=2ahUKEwi88djGv5HiAhWVfysKHcBxCTcQFjAAegQIBRAB&usg=AOvVaw1dFOh-DeahAfVHb_uTEfty)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the documentation you mention you'll find how to add a Game Object to a group like this

```
var group = scene.add.group(config);
group.add(gameObject);
```

But in fact if you take a look at [The Collider Callback Notes](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/arcade-world/#collider-callback) and [The Physics Group Notes](https://rexrainbow.github.io/phaser3-rex-notes/docs/site/arcade-gameobject/#add-physics-object) to create a group with collision you have to do something like this

```
var group = this.physics.add.group();
this.physics.add.collider(player, group, myHandler);
```

That will fires the `myHandler` function everytime the player collide with the group you are calling OBS by just replacing `group` by its name aka OBS

Of course you have to enable the body but I think by just adding the group like this it should work because am still in the logic of Phaser 2 CE actually and passing to v3

Now to answer the second part of your question, in fact a group can be seen as an array in fact depending on how you've coded your game you'll be able to access a certain Game Object in your group with `group.getChildren();`

Comment: You mean something like this : group.getChildren([1]);

Comment: If you try it what does get ? `console.log(OBS.getChildren([0]))`

Comment: As you have sprites it means that your problem is fixed

Comment: How do you isolate the member of the group that was collided with to call *its* `myHandler` function? Something like `this.physics.add.collider(player, group, memberOfGroup.handler);` ?